# If both N and G/N are cyclic, then G is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or disprove that if both N and G/N are cyclic, then G is cyclic.

N is a normal subgroup of a group G.

I think it is false but I can't find a counter example.

Comment: Try the Klein-4 group, the smallest example of a non-cyclic group

Comment: Or with $\;G=S_3\;,\;\;N=A_3\;,\;\;G/A_3\cong C_2\;$ , for a non-abelian counter example

Answer (score 0):

Hint $G = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} = \{ (a;b) |a\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge b\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ with the normal + operation defined on each component. $G$ is Abelian, hence every subgroup of it is indeed normal. Let $N = \{(a; 0) | a\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset G$. What you have to do now is to:

1. Use the First Isomorphism Theorem for Groups to prove that: $G/N \cong \{ (0; b) | b\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ hence cyclic.
2. Prove that $N$ is cyclic (obviously).
3. Finally, prove that $G$ is not cylic.